# Python Visualization from 3D array

Tags: python, 3d, visualization

Quick background: I'm a pretty proficient programmer when it comes to MATLAB, but am experimenting with learning python for fun and out of curiousity. I'm working on windows (will be dual booting again soon after this experience...) and am using anaconda (3.6), as I needed Scipy and, being new, figuring out the setup on windows was difficult at best.

I am working on 3D path planning for UAVs. I have a 3D array (say 1000x500x50) where unobstructed space has a value of zero and "no fly zones" have a value of 1. I can create variable terrains representative of a forest with trees, varrying floors, etc. and I'd like a simple way to view this environment. I could sort of get away with doing this as a point cloud by subsampling, increasing density, and then displaying it, but that is a less than ideal solution.

I've been perusing mayavi as a possible method for doing this, but I haven't been able to find examples of this kind of scale. I did write a script to draw a patch for each face of each obstructed cube, and this does work but is horribly inefficinet. Just looking for a better solution if one exists. Also, mayavi doesn't seem to be supported in anaconda yet (at least in 3.6), so I'd like a little more of a lead before I start switching builds again. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What you are looking for is called voxel rendering. It is not too difficult to write a basic 1-bit voxel svg renderer (just draw cubes on screen, and since it is 1-bit, you don't even need to sort them). If you need it to be real-time, OpenGL is your friend and not much harder

Comment: Did you try this: http://vispy.org/index.html ?

Comment: Thank you taylor swift. I did some quick googling and you are right, this is exactly what I was looking for. I will spend some time researching and see if I can't get something up and running.

Vispy looks like a really cool package, an no, I had not seen that one yet. I will play with this too and see if I can't find a simple pre-canned solution for the problem in front of my nose. Thanks for putting it on my radar, David!

Comment: @JayL Vispy is a promising project. I'm a python fanatic, but I have to warn you that powerfull off-the-shell 3D visualization is one of the few things where Python might not be the best language. I'm writing myself a python library for 3D point cloud processing and after wasting a lot of time I ended up using https://threejs.org/ for the visualization. Goog news is that is easy to integrate other tools with Python.

Comment: pd. Don't go back to Matlab because of this. Keep it up with Python for all your other needs!